# Overflow hidden issue

Tags: css

Does anyone know why `overflow: hidden` doesn't work in the below example? 
I want to achieve that the black bar slides right inside the `.product-btn` if someone hovers over it.

```css
.product-btn{
width: 250px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #f39c12;
background-color: #fff;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;
overflow: hidden;

}
.product-btn:before{
content: " ";
position: absolute; 

left: -125px;
width: 250px;
height: 50px;
background-color: black;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;



}
.product-btn:hover:before {
left: 125px;

}

.product-btn-text{
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 
 
}
.product-btn: hover {
color: red;
z-index: 1;
cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="product-btn">
<span class="product-btn-text">Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried .product-btn { position: relative;} added in selector?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set the `position:absolute` to the `:before` element which is relative to your document not to your `.product-btn`.

It means your `:before` element is out of `.product-btn`. So applying `overflow:hidden` will not work in the `:before` element

Just set the position:relative to the `.product-btn`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.product-btn {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #f39c12;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.product-btn:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -125px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.product-btn:hover:before {
  left: 125px;
}

.product-btn-text {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.product-btn: hover {
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-btn">
  <span class="product-btn-text">Text</span>
</div>
```